Jetpack Compose: After taking a picture and pressing back, users can't click on take a picture again
I'm using Jetpack Compose and I have a modal bottom sheet where users can click on Take a picture when the bottom sheet pops up. Then they get to the camera view and after taking a picture, they click OK and the picture will be uploaded to a server. So far so good.
The problem here comes when the user is in the camera view (where they can either click on OK to submit the picture they took or cancel) and they press the hardware back button or the cancel button. In this case, the camera view is dismissed and when they click on Take a picture again, nothing happens.
The code I have is this:
@Composable
fun AppModalBottomSheet(
    onShowBottomSheetChanged: (Boolean) -> Unit,
    onPictureTaken: (File, Long) -> Unit,
    onError: () -> Unit
) {
    var shouldShowCameraView by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var shouldShowRationale by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var shouldCheckForPermissions by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val multiplePermissionsLauncher =
        rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) {
            if (it.values.find { granted -> !granted } == true) {
                shouldShowRationale = true
            }
        }
    val permissionLauncher =
        rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) {
            if (it) {
                shouldShowCameraView = true
                shouldShowRationale = false
            } else {
                shouldShowCameraView = false
                shouldShowRationale = true
            }
        }

    val checkForMultiplePermissions: @Composable (MultiplePermissionsState) -> Unit = {
        val permissionState = rememberMultiplePermissionsState(
            listOf(
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            )
        )
        LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
            multiplePermissionsLauncher.launch(
                arrayOf(
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                )
            )
        }
        when (permissionState.allPermissionsGranted) {
            true -> {
                shouldShowCameraView = true
                shouldShowRationale = false
            }

            false -> {
                shouldShowCameraView = false
                shouldShowRationale = true
            }
        }
    }
    val checkForSinglePermission: @Composable (PermissionState) -> Unit = {
        val permissionState = rememberPermissionState(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
        LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
            permissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
        }
        when (permissionState.status) {
            is PermissionStatus.Denied -> {
                shouldShowCameraView = false
                shouldShowRationale = true
            }

            PermissionStatus.Granted -> {
                shouldShowCameraView = true
                shouldShowRationale = false
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ShowCamera(
    onPictureTaken: (file: File, fileSize: Long) -> Unit,
    onError: () -> Unit,
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val imageFile = remember { createImageFile(context) }
    val file = imageFile.getOrElse { onError.invoke() } as? File
    val fileUri = file?.let { FileUtils.uri(context, file) }
    val cameraLauncher =
        rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract = ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()) {
            if (it) {
                fileUri?.let { uri ->
                    val fileSize = FileUtils.fileSize(context, uri)
                    onPictureTaken(file, fileSize)
                }
            }
        }
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
        cameraLauncher.launch(fileUri)
    }
}

private fun createImageFile(context: Context): Result<File> {
    val timeStamp: String =
        SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
    val imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_"
    val storageDir: File? = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
    return runCatching {
        File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,
            ".jpeg",
            storageDir
        )
    }
}

After clicking back when they're in the camera view, when debugging, I set a breakpoint in the line with if (shouldShowCameraView) { and I can see shouldShowCameraView$delegate being true, but the ShowCamera() function never gets called.
Is there anything I'm missing here?

Where do you set shouldShowCameraView to true?

Where are you handling the user not selecting a picture? I don't see an else for your if (it) logic in your rememberLauncherForActivityResult.

@CommonsWare I've updated the questions with the code where shouldShowCameraView = true

@ianhanniballake I'm not handling that, indeed, but even if I handle it, with a callback such as the following, it still doesn't work:
            onPictureTaken = onPictureTaken,
            onPictureNotTaken = { shouldShowCameraView = true },
            onError = onError
        )```
